# How to change the default printer

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am attempting to change the default printer in the on change event of a combo box that list the printer index. I use "Printers" to get the printer index but the actual printing is done with proprietary print code that allows for direct to pdf printing and easier page layout. I am trying to use the below code to change the default printer and then my print code will print to that printer. However the program becomes unresponsive without any errors or program not responding messages when this line of code executes:

```
SendMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0,LongInt(cs1));
```

Here is the full function.

```
function TMainFrm.SetDefaultPrinter(const PrinterName: string): boolean;
// Printername is bv: '\\MYPRINTER\HP5-k'
var
s2 : string;
dum1 : Pchar;
xx, qq : integer;

const
cs1 : pchar = 'Windows';
cs2 : pchar = 'Device';
cs3 : pchar = 'Devices';
cs4 : pchar = #0;

begin
    xx := 254;
    GetMem( dum1, xx);
    Result := False;
    try
        qq := GetProfileString( cs3, pchar( PrinterName ), #0, dum1, xx);
    if (qq > 0) and (trim( strpas( dum1 )) <> '') then
    begin
        s2 := PrinterName + ',' + strpas( dum1 );
        while GetProfileString( cs1, cs2, cs4, dum1, xx) > 0 do
            WriteProfileString( cs1, cs2, #0);
            WriteProfileString( cs1, cs2, pchar( s2 ));
        case Win32Platform of
        VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT :
            SendMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0,LongInt(cs1));
        VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS :
            SendMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,LongInt(cs1));
        end; { case }
        Result := True;
    end;
    finally
        FreeMem( dum1 );
    end;
end;
```

Anyone have any tips or a better way to do this?

As a side note this is not my function. It's a piece of code I picked up while searching for a solution to my problem.

Few more pieces of info:

[image: The user selects the printer in the drop down. This is where the PDF will be sent]

The print job is actually a PDF being printed using

```
 ShellExecute(Application.Handle, 'print', PChar(sPath), nil, nil, SW_HIDE);
```

The goal is to change the default printer to the selected printer in order to print the pdf to the desired printer and then return the printer to the original default on exit of the application

Comment: Did you try `Printers.PrinterIndex := IndexOfYourPrinter`

Comment: I have not. I assumed that Printers.PrinterIndex would only work if I was using printers to print instead of the custom print class we use. I will test it and see if that gives me the desired result

Comment: Was worth a shot but my custom print class uses the default printer to print and Printers.PrinterIndex doesn't change the default

Comment: You shouldn't use the default printer. You should use the selected printer. Changing the default printer is something that the user should do. You must not do it behind their back.

Comment: You don't need the platform case, since `WM_WININICHANGE = WM_SETTINGCHANGE`.

Comment: The class allows the user to select their printer and normally uses the selected printer...however in this instance the application I am working on prints directly to pdf it then allows the user to print a hardcopy of said pdf. The shellexecute command is used to print the pdf file and the shellexecute is using the default printer it appears. So I guess in reality the use of the custom print class vs printers is moot

Comment: Just to reiterate, changing the default printer is akin to changing the default browser. If you are doing this on your own machine no problems, but if you put this code on other people's machines they will not be happy.

Comment: @David: I understand your point and agree with it. However in this instance I have no choice. Everything is designed to give them the feeling they are selecting their printer and default switch happens and restores to their choice without any impact on them. In the case of default browser swap it's rather obvious but in this case all they know is their print job is printing the pdf to the printer they choose in the reports program and that their default printer is what they set it as 99.9%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a brief look at [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246772) and it appears you're mising the most critical function SetDefaultPrinterA/SetDefaultPrinterW in 'winspool.drv'

Also the broadcast message is designed to be polite to other running programs to let them know something has changed the default printer, even in the above article it doesn't seem to pay any attention to the result so you could change the call to PostMessage

Comment: PostMessage solved the issue. Program operates as intended now thanks @JamesB

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [`Win32_Printer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class to list the printers and the [`SetDefaultPrinter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to set the default printer.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;

procedure  ListPrinters;
const
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT DeviceID, Name FROM Win32_Printer','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('DeviceID %s Name %s',[FWbemObject.DeviceID,FWbemObject.Name]));
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;

function  SetDefaultPrinter(const DeviceID:string):boolean;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('localhost', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
  FWbemObject   := FWMIService.Get(Format('Win32_Printer.DeviceID="%s"',[DeviceID]));
  if not VarIsClear(FWbemObject) then
   Result:=FWbemObject.SetDefaultPrinter()=0
  else
   Result:=false;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      ListPrinters;
      SetDefaultPrinter('HP LaserJet'); //here you must pass the DeviceID of one the printers listed above
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to use the "SendMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0,LongInt(cs1))" code block and my program was hang. So, I tried to simply write the SetDefaultPrinter as local function and then no hang occours. Here is the code that works fine for me.

```
function SetDefaultPrinter(const PrinterName: string): boolean;
// Printername is bv: '\\MYPRINTER\HP5-k'
var
s2 : string;
dum1 : PChar;
xx, qq : integer;

const
cs1 : pChar = 'Windows';
cs2 : pChar = 'Device';
cs3 : pChar = 'Devices';
cs4 : pChar = #0;

begin
    xx := 254;
    GetMem( dum1, xx);
    Result := False;
    try
            qq := GetProfileString( cs3, pChar( PrinterName ), #0, dum1, xx);
            if (qq > 0) and (trim( strpas( dum1 )) <> '') then
            begin
                s2 := PrinterName + ',' + strpas( dum1 );
                while GetProfileString( cs1, cs2, cs4, dum1, xx) > 0 do
                    WriteProfileString( cs1, cs2, #0);
                    WriteProfileString( cs1, cs2, pChar( s2 ));

                case Win32Platform of
                VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT :
                    SendMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_WININICHANGE, 0, LongInt(cs1));
                VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS :
                    SendMessage( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0,LongInt(cs1));
                end; { case }
                Result := True;
            end;
    finally
        FreeMem( dum1 );
    end;
end;
```